# Get particular date format in php?

Tags: php, date, format

How can I get a date to look like this format?

Year-month-day-hour-minute-second

2012-06-29-09-06-11

This is what I have so far.

```
$date = new DateTime;
$time = $date->format('y-m-d-h-m-s');
```

The above results gives this

12-06-29-09-06-11

I ran this at 3:07 pm eastern time.

As you can see its not quite what I want. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a timezone to the `DateTime` constructor, in addition to using a capital `Y` to get the four-digit year and `i` to get the minutes:

```
$date = new DateTime( "now", new TimeZone( "America/New_York"));
$time = $date->format('Y-m-d-h-i-s');
```

The [list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) will allow you to select the one you need (I believe I chose the correct one for EST).

Your current string uses `m` for both months and minutes, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime;
$time = $date->format('Y-m-d-h-m-s');
```

y - 2 digits

Y - 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d-h-i-s');
```

Also don't forget to set your timezone using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)
eg:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PEAR library of DATE and read its docs to get the desired result.